# Make a trapezoid with css3 border radius

Tags: css

I want to make a trapezoid with border radius like this picture. Is it possible?

[image: this image]

I tried this code but it does not work

```
background: #BE1E2D;
width: 130px; 
height: 75px;
-webkit-transform: skew(20deg); 
-moz-transform: skew(20deg); 
-o-transform: skew(20deg);
transform: skew(20deg);
```

Comment: Is it homework??Please try something

Comment: Have people stopped making a Google search before asking? http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Comment: Your code works fine, just change all of the `20deg` to `-20deg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visit this website to look at how a lot of shapes are done.](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

For this shape though (as it is on the website), you need this:

```
#parallelogram {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Doesn't use `border-radius` though.

```
.trapezoid{
     width:100px; 
     height:100px; 
     border:1px solid #000; 
     background:yellow;
     transform: skew(-20deg); 
     -o-transform: skew(-20deg); 
     -moz-transform: skew(-20deg); 
     -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could do this with `border-radius` (or why you would want to)

You can do it with a simple skew:

```
#shape {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-25deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(-25deg);
         -o-transform: skew(-25deg);
    background: darkred;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W4dd3/)